# Map properties path as function arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have a function that basically sorts a MAP of MAP's, but it uses different MAP properties for the sort, so i want to sort by age or by name based on the user input.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "other_data:
  {
     "age": "20",
     "nickname": "Doe2020"
  }
}
```

So my idea was to make a generic function to sort this. There is some way where i can send the path of each property as a function argument to sort based on this argument ?

Like "mySortFunction(MapPath: ["other_data"]["age"]);"
or "mySortFunction(MapPath: ["name"]);"

Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, it is nonsensical to want to sort maps since you will be generally accessing them by index, not by order. Maybe this question could better be answered if you explained how you intended to sort the maps and for what purpose. You may find that it is more prudent to have the internal maps be converted to lists instead.

Comment: Its a list of "games" that come from the API. So when i want to display the whole list i just run trough the list calling widgets for each object. But this map has to be order, alphabetically, by release date, the most used games...

So for this its good to use lists, but the user has the option to acess infos about the game, so i called them by ID for this is better maps, to avoid for each loops to search for the game on the list of maps.

Comment: I thins i wasnt clear on that, its a list of maps like:
[game..., game2...] i want to order this list by the map properties of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, if your properties are at max two levels:

```
mySortFunction(Map map, {String firstLevel, String secondLevel}){
  if(firstLevel != null){
    if(secondLevel != null){
      sortMap(map[firstLevel][secondLevel]); // Your sorting logic here
    } else {
      sortMap(map[firstLevel]); // sorting logic strikes back
    }
  }
}
```

You can add more optional variables and increase the `if` logic for deeper maps